# How do you open UDP ports in a range on MacOS 10.15.7 Catalina

Tags: macos, terminal, network, catalina, xcode

How do you open UDP ports in a range on MacOS 10.15.7 Catalina. For example, I'm trying to open these ports for Unity iOS debugging on device...

```
nc -vnzu 225.0.0.2222 55000-555111
nc: port range not valid
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason for your error message is that you have chosen the end of the port number range as "555111". However, port numbers in the IP protocol range from 0 to 65535, so 555111 is definitely too high.